# How do I add a list ID after already integrating MailChimp?

Tags: php, mailchimp

So there are two separate custom forms on my site that are integrated into MailChimp. At the moment they are both directed to the same list, which I've decided to change. I've already created the new list in MailChimp and have the new list ID, but I'm unaware as to what changes I need to make in the php now????

Answer (score 0):

David,

I'm assuming you have the list_id in a hidden input.  Grab list_id using something like `$myListId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');` When you make your API call, use `$myListId`.